# stack level too deep after_save callback in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

My model is like this,

```
class Slot
  include Mongoid::Document
  after_save :calculate_period

  field :slot, type: Array

  def calculate_period
    if condition
     do something
    end
  self.slot = true
  save
  end

end
```

After submit button it will show this error,
SystemStackError in SlotsController#create
stack level too deep

and also consuming more time. If i remove the save from def calculate_period then the values are not storing after_save callback.

Any solution...!!!

Comment: you save in an after save: infinite loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this to before_save, that way you can change the model's attributes, and then they will be saved to the database as normal.

```
class Slot
  include Mongoid::Document
  before_save :calculate_period

  def calculate_period
    if condition
      #do something
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You have infinite loop - calling `save` in `calculate_period` method invokes callbacks, including your `calculate_period` callback. The first solution that came into my mind is to add virtual attribute and check it before calling your callback method:

```
class Slot
  include Mongoid::Document
  after_save :calculate_period, unless: :period_calculated # I'm not sure if Mongoid allows this
  attr_accessor :period_calculated

  def calculate_period
    if condition
      # do something
    end
    self.period_calculated = true
    save
  end
end
```

Comment: Did like you but giving error as fro array attribute, Problem: Value of type TrueClass cannot be written to a field of type Array Summary: Tried to set a value of type TrueClass to a field of type Array Resolution: Verify if the value to be set correspond to field definition

Comment: Sounds like something is mucking with what 'attr_accessor' means.  Likely some gem required by some gigantic chain of gems.  If you can write 5 lines of code instead of using a gem which requires other gems, you're much better off in the long run.